# Override Function Not Overriding (Csharp)

Tags: c#, overriding

I am in a game jam and I have been creating a conversion script. I made a base Interact virtual void In Unity in which each interactable will use public override void Interact() and do whatever is needed. My problem is that when I call Interact() in one my scripts only main function is being called and not the overriding function. I am using Unity 2017, Csharp.

**Base Interaction Script**

```
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour {

private NavMeshAgent NavAgent;
private bool isInteracting;

public virtual void MoveToLocation(NavMeshAgent navMesh)
{
    isInteracting = false;
    this.NavAgent = navMesh;
    NavAgent.stoppingDistance = 4;
    NavAgent.destination = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(!isInteracting && NavAgent != null && !NavAgent.pathPending)
    {
        if(NavAgent.remainingDistance <= NavAgent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            Interact();
            Debug.Log("Moving To Interactable");
            isInteracting = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isInteracting = false;
        }
    }
}

public virtual void Interact()
{
    Debug.Log("herro");
}
}
```

**NPC Interaction Script**

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

using UnityEngine;

public class NPC : Interactable {

//Setting Up Conversation Var
public string NPCName;
public string[] Conversation;
private int currentConversation;

//Gettig=ng UI
public CanvasGroup ConversationUI;
public Text Title;
public Text Text;

private void Start()
{
    currentConversation = 0;
}

public override void Interact()
{
    Debug.Log("Interacting With NPC");
    //Opening UI
    ConversationUI.alpha = 1;
    ConversationUI.interactable = true;
    ConversationUI.blocksRaycasts = true;
    //Setting Up Name
    Title.text = NPCName;
    Text.text = Conversation[currentConversation];
}

public void NextConv()
{
    currentConversation++;
    if (currentConversation >= Conversation.Length)
    {
        ConversationUI.alpha = 0;
        ConversationUI.interactable = false;
        ConversationUI.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
    else if (currentConversation < Conversation.Length)
    {
        Text.text = Conversation[currentConversation];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the instantiating/calling code? It sounds as if your object is being instantiated as a `Interactable` and not a `NPC`.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you are calling the Interact method

Comment: if(NavAgent.remainingDistance <= NavAgent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            Interact();
            Debug.Log("Moving To Interactable");
            isInteracting = true;
        }  That is  the code that calls the function